# How to measure real time refreshing data (Kbps) incoming and outgoing in android? (Not Link Speed)

Tags: android, performance

Can anyone please tell me 
How I can measure real time internet speed in Kbps in android programmatically. I am a beginner in Android Development. Please Help me to solve my problem.

This is just like we can see in windows Task Manager the current wifi Statistics. I just want to get the current speed.